# Material UI AutoComplete not rendering on remote dataSource in React application

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui, jsx

I am using React 15.0.1 and Material-UI 0.15.0. I am trying to render an autocomplete through React. Here's my code:

```js
import React from 'react';

import SomeService from '../../../services/SomeService';

import AutoComplete from 'material-ui/AutoComplete';

class SearchInput extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      dataSource: []
    };
  }
  
  searchSomething (value) {
    if (value.length) {
      SomeService.fetchAutocomplete({searchQuery: value})
        .then((res) => this.handleSuccess(res.data),
              (err) => this.handleFailure(err));
    } else {
      this.setState({
        dataSource: []
      });
    }
  };
  handleSuccess (response) {
    this.setState({dataSource: response.slice(0, 10)});
  }
  handleFailure (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <AutoComplete
          floatingLabelText='Enter test'
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          onUpdateInput={(val) => this.searchSomething(val)}
          fullWidth={true} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchInput;
```

Assuming I get a response object with data: [...] // an array of stuff.
This is not being rendered.

The response object is something like:

```js
reponse: {
  ....,
  data: ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange'],
  ....
}
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: can you show an example of the object? Name of the properties..

Comment: Response object?
`response: {
  ....,
  data: ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', ....],
  .....
}`

Comment: if u add a console in your `render` function you can see those values right?

Comment: Also, that `onUpdateInput` function is called for each character you type.. so you can have problems doing many requests.. - I suggest you to debounce it in 500ms for example

Comment: @AndréJunges Yes I get the values. Let me try debouncing.

Comment: @AndréJunges I am getting result for 2 and 3 characters entered. Not happening for any other entry length.

Comment: Case sensitivity? Might be worth trying a case insensitive filter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/3630#issuecomment-226003483) issue and mentioned comment, you just had to skip filter function by passing true for everything.

```
    <AutoComplete
          floatingLabelText='Enter test'
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          onUpdateInput={(val) => this.searchSomething(val)}
          fullWidth={true} 
          filter={(searchText, key) => true} />
```

Comment: Okay. Let me try this.

Comment: @ni8mare is that a fix?

Comment: yup this fixes it. Thanks.